# How can I invert X-axis and Y-axis?

Tags: 2010, chart-web-part

I'm working on sharepoint 2010. Here is my problem : I have a chart webpart which display my x-axis horizontally and my y-axis vertically. I want to know if it's possible to display the opposite : y-axis horizontally and x-axis vertically.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to show the values orientation? what is your data source?

Answer (score 0):

On the "Bind Chart to Data" page, you can specify which column is the X axis and which is the Y axis. This is done as a last step, after you've specified the data source and any filtering you might want.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that. I don't know why, but some fields are not available in the Y-Axis in particular the one I want to have on the Y-Axis. That's why I invert axis...